Automatically changing the bill for auto-renewal
For our membership, we calculate the price by minimum amount * number relationships. To adjust the price, we calculate the total cost and use the buildAmount hook to change the price when a user loads in the contribution form. I realized that this would most probably not work with auto renewal since that form does not have to be accessed when paying (unless I'm wrong).
The issue here is the number of relationships can change after the initial membership if a relationship is cancelled or moved to another type of relationship so I can't just set the auto renewal price at the beginning of the membership.
Is there a hook or something where I can do the same thing I did with buildform, but use it to automatically change the price of the auto renewal. I am using Stripe if that helps.
Thank you!

sounds like you need something built to update the value in "amount" field in table civicrm_contribution_recur shortly prior to the 'next_sched_contribution_date' coming around. this is also what we had to do as a one-off for when a client changed their Memb Fees but as a one-off we could just sort via mysql query
